# How I can display information in pie chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I found the next pie chart with Chart.js [pie chart](http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/wprnvyd1/)

```
var dataPTD = [
            {
                label: "Single Family Residence",
                color: "#5093ce",
                highlight: "#78acd9",
                value: 52
            },
            {
                label: "Townhouse/Condo",
                color: "#c7ccd1",
                highlight: "#e3e6e8",
                value: 12
            }
```

How I can make to display only one tooltip at center of diagram and static, example:

display only "52" that correspond at "Single Family Residence"

Comment: like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7odt.png) ?

Comment: or like this: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68820/15855

Comment: Yes  ℊααnd , exactly that

Comment: lois6b Of course, I am adapting your answer to my project, and it is very similar to what I need

Comment: Jose, check now, I did what @ℊααnd sugested: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68820/15855

Comment: Oh yeah, wait please  lois6b